# C - printf with pow function issue

Tags: c, printf

I am trying to learn some C and I have an issue I can't figure out.  Seems pretty simple but the below is not working.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    printf("%f", pow(4, 3) );
    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
Implicitly declaring library function 'pow' with type 'double (double, double)'
```

I have the string formatter set to float so I am not sure why I am seeing that error

Comment: `#include <math.h>`

Comment: What header contains the function prototype for the pow function?

Comment: That's not an error, it's a warning. You can still run the executable

Comment: @EugeneSh.  Thank you. The tutorial I am watching does not have that in the code, I dont know how theirs is even running.  It matches mine exactly.  Adding that fixed it.

Comment: Be very careful with C tutorials, many of them are really not worth the time. Always have a [high-quality reference book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) on hand to validate anything you're being taught.

Comment: Tutorials are not perfect. Some are really bad.

Comment: @Dock, whether it's a warning or error is configurable in most compilers. Many of us would treat that as an error.

Comment: I have a "C - Primer Plus" book I bought years ago but never really looked at.  Maybe I would be better off working with that :). Thanks everyone

Comment: @Dock. Without prototype the compiler will assume `int` type return value and only pass an `int` to `printf` which might not be a syntax error but will still result in garbage.

Answer (score 0):

The `pow()` is in `math.h` header file.
The format specifier for `double` should be used.

https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/library-function/math.h/pow

Comment: What's wrong with the format specifier? `printf` expects a `double` argument for `%f`.

Comment: I mistakenly commented (deleted) that `%lf` should be used, but that is for `scanf()`. The `%f` with `printf()` is good, and `float` is promoted to `double`.

Answer (score 0):

include library `#include <math.h>`
and change `printf("%f", pow(4, 3) )` line to `printf("%lf", pow(4, 3) )`
, because `pow()` returns double

Comment: `%f` is fine for `double` in printing.

Comment: @EricPostpischil +1